# Compared with spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE, spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE-sources lack many classes?

Tags: spring, maven, cglib

I find that many classes in maven jar org.springframework:spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE can not be found in org.springframework:spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE-sources, such as org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor. Not only the version 5.2.8.RELEASE has such problem.

Comment: I'm able to find the class in the jar. How are you checking that the class is present or not?

Comment: That is because cglib (and asm and other libs) are re-packaged by spring to prevent  clashes with versions of those libraries. They are packaged upon building and the sources aren't from Spring but from those libs, hence they aren't in the sources jars.

Comment: I'm sure I have got the right answer from 
M. Deinum, thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.